# Pass data to child component that can be called multiple times

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a parent component and use ViewChild to call the method in child component. However, when I load the data and use that method to pass data, It show the error my method is undefined. Where did I get it wrong?

**Flow:** 
At first: After NgOnInit() method, I load the data and pass It to the child component
Second try: I use NgAfterViewInit() to load the data end then pass it to the child component but it has the same error

**Note:** The parent has a variable that can create child component multiple times

Sample Code with further [description](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-t917aq):

Comment: Hi NguYen welcome to SO. Can you please include code as well

Comment: Please replicate your example with stackblitz and post a link or add the content of yout parent/child ts files.

Comment: Here it is: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-t917aq. The sample code is related to mine. And I have some description to make it clearer

Comment: Please post this code example into your question for future reference. Other users who looks for the same problem might won't find your link later anymore. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass data to the child using the `@Input` decorator. The theory:

1. Pass data through this `input`
2. Fire change detection to handle those changes
   Parent TS:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
}
```

Parent HTML :

```
<app-child [name]="name"></app-child>
```

Child TS:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  templateUrl: './app-child.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app-child.component.css' ]
})
export class AppChildComponent  {
  @Input() name = '';

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    if (changes.name) {
      this.setup();
    }
  }

  setup() {
     ...
  }
}
```

Inside setup of the child you can then handle the data as expected.